# Form validation - array loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, which works nicely:

```
$('#register form .submit input').click(function(){    
    if(jQuery.trim($('#new-usr').val()) == '' || jQuery.trim($('#new-pwd').val()) == '' || jQuery.trim($('#new-pwd-confirm').val()) == ''){
      alert('Please fill in every required field (marked with an asterisk)');
      return false;
    }    
  });
```

However, I have a lot more fields to add to this and was thinking that there must be a way of storing the input ids in an array and looping through them, rather than adding a `jquery.trim($('#inputid').val()) == ''` for each one.

The jQuery validation plugin is a no-go in this instance for reasons that are too boring to go into here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try:

```
$('#register form .submit input').click(function(){    
    var success = true;
    $("#register form .required").each(function(){
        if(this.value === ""){
            success = false;
        }
    });
    if(!success){
        alert('Please fill in every required field (marked with an asterisk)');
        return false;
    };
});
```

and give all your required fields the class `required`

**EDIT**
this should do it than:

```
$('#register form .submit input').click(function(){    
    var success = true;
    $("#new-usr, #new-pwd, #new-pwd-confirm").each(function(){
        if(this.value === ""){
            success = false;
        }
    });
    if(!success){
        alert('Please fill in every required field (marked with an asterisk)');
        return false;
    };
});
```

Comment: I can't get at the html to add the class, I'm afraid, hence the inability to use the validation plugin, thanks though.

Comment: @ScottBrown in that case you should replace the `#register form .required` with a selector that can select all required fields another way, something like `#new-usr, #new-pwd, #new-pwd-confirm`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this (using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over selection - not really an array, but a lot easier to maintain):

```
$('#register form .submit input').click(function(){ 
  // add IDs here
  //     vvv  
  $('#new-usr, #new-pwd, #new-pwd-confirm').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()) == ''){
      alert('Please fill in every required field (marked with an asterisk)');
      return false;
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I always forget about `.each()`, thanks. The validation works great but for some reason it's not returning false. Any ideas why?

Comment: because the return false is for the `each` function and not for the `submit` function

Comment: @red-X: thanks for the hint, i missed that  -your solution is clearly the better one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UDCWB/

Simply add a required class to your input variables and use jQuery to loop through them.